# How to convert Azure date into friendly date?

Tags: azure, date

In azure I am using an api, and I get back this in the json response.

```
Date(1533024552000)
```

Does anyone know how to convert that into a regular date like `July 2 2018` for example?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [UnixDateTimeConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.unixdatetimeconverter?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=azure-dotnet) class. Converts a DateTime object to and from JSON. DateTime is represented as the total number of seconds that have elapsed since January 1, 1970 (midnight UTC/GMT), not counting leap seconds (in ISO 8601: 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z).

```
    public class AzureResponse
    {
        [JsonConverter(typeof(UnixDateTimeConverter))]
        public DateTime Date;
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        AzureResponse input = new AzureResponse() { Date = new DateTime(2018,7,31,10,09,12)};
        string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input);
        // "{\"Date\":1533031752}"

        AzureResponse readBack = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AzureResponse>(output);
        // Date = {31.07.2018 10:09:12}
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Epoch, also known as Unix timestamps, is the number of seconds (not milliseconds!) that have elapsed since January 1, 1970 at 00:00:00 GMT (1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT). https://www.freeformatter.com/epoch-timestamp-to-date-converter.html